# Delete image in directory after using SELECT statement PHP

Tags: php, file, pdo

I have a prepared statement here:

```
 $stmt2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT img_path FROM products WHERE id = :id");
 $stmt2->bindParam(':id', $id);
 $stmt2->execute();
```

I want to get the value of "img_path" so i can delete an image to a directory using **unlink()** of PHP.
How will I do that?

I tried using this code but failed to delete the image file:

```
 unlink($stmt2->fetch());
```

I got this error:

`Invalid argument for unlink()`

Comment: You should use some debugging to see what `$stmt2->fetch()` is returning.

Comment: I got this error: **Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\MFC WEBSITE\product-delete.php on line 15**

Comment: That means that your connection failed! Show us your connection!

Comment: I already fixed it, it was on the connection. The problem now is that i got this error: **Invalid argument for unlink()**

Comment: @TheMartianGuy I think you should read some tutorials on how to debug code.  This site looks relevant: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-debug-in-php, specifically the section "Using var_dump() to Aid Your Debugging"

Comment: You should add the answer as an answer, not as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed this issue by using this following code:

```
 $result = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 unlink($result['img_path']);
```